# Netty - Allocating a List of reusable buffers via PooledByteBufAllocator

Tags: java, buffer, netty, pool

Picture a Netty app sending out data from several different sources of different data on the same channel.

On the sent data/out-bytes, each source will be identified by a specific header + the data from the source.

I am planning to use a small list of reusable buffers whose content (bytes) is updated with every new data block arriving from a given source. This approach of small set of reusable buffers per data source should save time on allocating direct buffers and simply writing the headers (of given source) and new data to the same memory area (of each given source buffers) over and over again. The content of the buffers is then send off /written to the socket channel from one of the two wrapped (combined) buffers (depending on a condition).

I am trying this approach, hoping that I can create 5 direct buffers (memory blocks) to the pool inside each DataSource class and keep reusing it. However, I am getting exception when trying to use the buffers anywhere further in the code.
Exception:
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0

```
public class DataSource {

    final List<ByteBuf> BUFFERS = new ArrayList<>();

    private void alocateHeaderBuffers() {

        ByteBufAllocator pbba = PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT;
        BUFFERS.add(0, pbba.directBuffer(32, 32));    // buffer of fixed size  32 bytes - header 1
        BUFFERS.add(1, pbba.directBuffer(128, 128));  // buffer of fixed size 128 bytes - header 2
        BUFFERS.add(2, pbba.directBuffer(256));       // buffer of minimum size 256 (can grow) - for data of various size
        // Two combined buffers using - Unpooled.wrappedBuffer():
        // Combine 2 buffers: 0 + 2
        // and buffers:       1 + 2
        BUFFERS.add(3, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(BUFFERS.get(0), BUFFERS.get(2)));
        BUFFERS.add(4, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(BUFFERS.get(1), BUFFERS.get(2)));
    }
}
```

Exception description - if I do:

```
    ByteBuf bb1 = BUFFERS.get(0);
    bb1.writeBytes(headerPrefix); // headerPrefix = 4 bytes array
```

bb1 is shown by debugger as 'freed'
and the next line throws:
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0

BUT
if I try it on the next buffer in the list:

```
    ByteBuf bb2 = BUFFERS.get(1);
    bb2.writeBytes(headerPrefix); // headerPrefix = 4 bytes array
```

that works fine. BUT

```
    ByteBuf bb3 = BUFFERS.get(2);
    bb3.writeBytes(headerPrefix); // headerPrefix = 4 bytes array
```

fails the same way as bb1.

Comment: "However, I am getting error"...which is?

Comment: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
Debugger shows the BUFFERS[0] as freed

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

> This approach of small set of reusable buffers per data source should
>   save time on allocating direct buffers

, that's exactly what the `PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT` is. Part of the reason why it pools buffers is to avoid long allocation times for direct `ByteBuf`s.

So by allocating a series of ByteBufs from the pooled allocator, you're  permanently reserving pooled resources that are supposed to be shared.

If you are intent on continuing your approach, I would simply pre-allocate your buffers from the default [UnpooledByteBufAllocator](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/UnpooledByteBufAllocator.html) using [directBuffer(int)](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/AbstractByteBufAllocator.html#directBuffer-int-)

Answer (score 1):

You also opened a bug in the [netty issue tracker](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8103#issuecomment-403237326) in which I explain that I think it works as documented in the java docs. I think you are right it may be a bit surprising and hard to reason about but again it matches exactly the javadocs.

That said as mentioned in the issue we deprecated this method and introduced a replacement which does not give this "surprising behaviour". This will be part of 4.1.26.Final.

See https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/8040 and https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/8096.

Answer (score 0):

After further testing there appears to be this issue. After allocating the initial 3 buffers and then using:

```
 Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(BUFFERS.get(0), BUFFERS.get(2));
 System.out.println(bb1.refCnt()); // returns 0  !!!
```

and any of the underlying / referenced buffers (e.g. 0 and 2) are empty - no data written to them yet, the empty buffers get freed by the call to the wrappedBuffer() method. The refcount() on the empty buffer returns 0.

On the other hand, if we place some data in the referenced buffer before we call the wrappedBuffer() method, the buffer does not get freed and refcount() on that buffer returns 1.

```
 HEADER_BUFFERS.get(0).writeBytes(headerPrefix);
 Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(BUFFERS.get(0), BUFFERS.get(2));
 System.out.println(bb1.refCnt()); // returns 1  !!!
```

Perhaps this is a feature to auto-release unused memory, but in this case it presents itself rather as a bug. Hopefully it is something Netty designers/insiders could clear up for us.

A further research provides a work around / solution - use  .retain():

```
Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(BUFFERS.get(0).retain(), BUFFERS.get(2).retain());
```